# sql "ranges" and wildcards

Tags: sql

Complete sql noob here.

Trying to think about a way to store some data in a table that looks a little like this:

> "0-15", "low", "1-3"
>
> "45-50", "med", "*"
>
> "*", "*", "1000"

where column 1 & 3 are ranges of integers, and col 2 is an enumerated type (could be stored as whatever really).

i want to be able to put in wildcards in the table to keep the number of rows down while still not "missing" anything.

from what i understand it, column 1 & 3 would be best stored as two columns of integers each, with -INT_MAX to INT_MAX or whatever as a "wildcard". (select bla from bla where col1.1 > val and col1.2 < val)

is this a reasonable strategy?

column 2 seems trickier, select bla from bla where col2 = 'med' or col2 ='*' doesn't seem right. i could probably do these numerically just like 1 & 3 but would rather not

anyone care to enlighten me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preference would be to use `NULL` as the wildcard, since it will stand out prominently to any human studying the database.  In that case, each element of your `WHERE` clauses will look something like this:

```
WHERE (77777 > min_value OR min_value IS NULL)
  AND (77777 < max_value OR max_value IS NULL)
  AND (col2 = 'med' OR col2 IS NULL)
```

This is the same basic idea of the `*` you had before, but using a value that SQL recognizes as being different from ordinary values.

Comment: ok, i just kind of wanted confirmation of my suspicion :)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

A natural thing to do, given SQL, would be to use `NULL` as your wildcard value.